# Find correspondent numbers in integer intervals

Tags: r

I would like to get the correspondent numbers between two integers intervals. My input is like that:

```
    start1  end1    start2  end2    
      20     30      25      35
      25     35      20      30    
     100     190    126      226      
     126     226    100      190
```

In the first and second line, the overlap from first(1) interval (2 first collumns) to second(2) interval (2 last collumns) was equal to 6 correspondents numbers (25,26,27,28,29 and 30).

My expected output is like that:

```
start1  end1    start2  end2    bp_overlapped   
   20    30       25      35          6        
   25    35       20      30          6
  100    190     126     226          65
  126    226     100     190          65
```

It is a matrix in R.

Thank you.

Comment: If any of the answers we gave you solved your problem you should accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you are searching for is intersect. You can do this if `X` is your first matrix:

```
f <- function(x)
    length( intersect(seq(x[1],x[2],1), seq(x[3],x[4],1)) )
a <- apply(X,1,f)
X <- cbind(X,a)
```

The function `apply` applies a function on a each row of a matrix (if its second argument is 1) or on each column (if its second argument is 2).

Comment: Sorry the newbie question, but I have to put my dataframe name just in "X" or in "X" and "x". Moreover, the number one (X,1 and [1]) is always the number of start1 collumn?

Comment: You just have to replace `X`. `x` is the parameter of the function. I will edit my post to make it clearer ;)

Comment: This appears:Error in if (d2 == 0L) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: Weird... It works for me. Do you have any NA value  in you data.frame ? Could post a the results of the function `dput` applied to your dataframe (if it is not too big...) ?

Comment: I get whit a code variation: overlap <- apply(X, 1, function(x) length(intersect(x[1]:x[2], x[3]:x[4])))

What´s the main difference from results expected from your code?
My data have almost 5000 lines, and no NAs

Comment: There is no difference when I test it on the data you provided in your question. There must be a difference in the data which you are running the test on and the data of your example. The problem is that I do not understand the error you are getting (I do not know what is `d2`).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a vectorized solution that is hard to beat in terms of speed. In case you have a lot of segments (as you often do in biology, which is what I guess you do from the term `bp_overlapped`) it makes a big difference.

```
pmax(
    0,                  # Returns 0 if the segments do not overlap at all
    1 + pmin(
        end1 - start1,  # Returns the length of seg 1 in case it is inside seg 2
        end2 - start2,  # Returns the length of seg 2 in case it is inside seg 1
        end1 - start2,  # Returns the overlap in case seg 1 is left of seg 2
        end2 - start1   # Returns the overlap in case seg 2 is left of seg 1
    )
)
```